# Add a SCSI disk on Linux without rebooting

Tags: linux, sata, scsi

I added new disk to my running Linux virtual machine.

Is it possible to add a SCSI/SATA device explicitly, or to re-scan an entire SCSI/SATA host bus without rebooting a running Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There are some methods to do it:

**Add a single device**

```
 echo "scsi add-single-device <Host> <Bus> <Target> <Lun>" > /proc/scsi/scsi
```

In my case, I added the only SCSI/SATA disk on Host=8, so the command is

```
echo "scsi add-single-device 8 0 0 0" > /proc/scsi/scsi
```

**Rescan SCSI/SATA Host Bus**

If there were more than one disks added to your system, you can scan all devices on explicit SCSI/SATA Host

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/hostHOSTNUM/scan
```

I.e. if the disk was added to Host=8, the command is

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host8/scan
```

**Rescan all SCSI/SATA Hosts**

Generally, if you don't know a host number of added disk, you can scan the whole SCSI hosts on your machine.

*Get a list of SCSI/SATA hosts:*

1. Use **lsscsi** to get a list of hosts: `lsscsi -H`
2. Use **sysfs** to get a list of hosts: `ls -d /sys/class/scsi_host/host*`.

*Rescan given host:* `echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/hostX/scan`

**Simple full scan automation script**

```
#/bin/bash
# ReScan all SCSI/SATA Hosts
for SHOST in /sys/class/scsi_host/host*; do
    echo -n "Scanning ${SHOST##*/}..."
    echo "- - -" > ${SHOST}/scan
    echo Done
done
```

***Sources were used in this answer:***

[EVAN HOFFMAN'S BLOG](https://evanhoffman.com/2011/10/24/rescan-sata-bus-aka-hot-adding-a-sata-disk-on-a-linux-guest-in-vmware-without-rebooting/)

[nixCraft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/vmware-add-a-new-hard-disk-without-rebooting-guest.html)

[RedHat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1455393)